# Same file linked with Github gist and repo, two remotes

Tags: git, github, git-remote, gist

I have a private repository mainly with markdown files. I would like to make one of these files public through a gist, and be able to push to the two remotes. Is that possible?

This is what I did (MWE) - assume repo and gist already exist and gist file is in the root of the repo, with same name `shared_file.md`

```bash
git clone <my-repo>
git add remote gist git@gist.github.com:<gist-code>.git
git fetch gist
```

No errors/warnings so far.
Then I tried to edit `shared_file.md` locally and

```bash
git add shared_file.md
git commit -m "test"
git push -u gist main
```

What happens is that the file is (commited and) pushed to the repo remote and not to the Github gist.

I'm aware of the fact that it might not make sense, cause I feel I should ad least use another branch. Maybe it's not even possible to do. In that case, is there any way of achieving what stated in the beginning?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: How did you add the gist remote? Please be more specific.

Comment: `git add remote gist git@gist.github.com:<gist-code>.git` where the SSH address was taken from the gist GitHub page, dropdown _Embed_ menu